# How to remove second grep match in a single line?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

**Input file1**

```
BRAF      p.Gly464Val  Non-small cell p.Gly464Val   pathogenic
BAG3      p.His83Gln  AllHighlyPenetrant      p.His83Gln     pathogenic 
EYA4      p.Gly277Ser  AllHighlyPenetrant     p.Gly277Ser    pathogenic
```

**myCmd**

```
egrep "p\.[A-Z][a-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[A-Z][a-z]{1,}" file1
```

**Expected output**

```
BRAF      p.Gly464Val  Non-small cell  pathogenic
BAG3      p.His83Gln  AllHighlyPenetrant  pathogenic 
EYA4      p.Gly277Ser  AllHighlyPenetrant  pathogenic
```

How can i remove the second grep match? Any suggestion will be  appreciated.
thnx

Comment: i dont know how to use that..I am a newbie.Can you please demonstrate?

Comment: it's unclear. Does the input contains on;ly three lines?

Comment: Is second `grep match` always second last field?

Comment: @AvinashRaj : no there are 10k similar entries

Comment: @Jotne :  yes it is always second last

Answer (score 1):

If formatting is not important:

```
awk '{$(NF-1)=""}1' file
BRAF p.Gly464Val Non-small cell  pathogenic
BAG3 p.His83Gln AllHighlyPenetrant  pathogenic
EYA4 p.Gly277Ser AllHighlyPenetrant  pathogenic
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the repeated text always first appears as the second field:

```
$ cat input.txt
BRAF      p.Gly464Val  Non-small cell p.Gly464Val   pathogenic
BAG3      p.His83Gln  AllHighlyPenetrant      p.His83Gln     pathogenic
EYA4      p.Gly277Ser  AllHighlyPenetrant     p.Gly277Ser    pathogenic

$ sed -r 's/^([^ ]* *)([^ ]*)(.*)(\2 *)(.*)/\1\2\3\5/' input.txt
BRAF      p.Gly464Val  Non-small cell pathogenic
BAG3      p.His83Gln  AllHighlyPenetrant      pathogenic
EYA4      p.Gly277Ser  AllHighlyPenetrant     pathogenic
```

Explanation:

1. The first bracket matches first field & spaces after that.
2. Second bracket matches second field.
3. Third bracket matches any text till the 2nd field is found again.
4. Then match the repeated 2nd field & any spaces after that.
5. Match anything remaining in last bracket.
6. Finally, replace it with everything except repeated 2nd field.

Comment: +2 for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The following command should do the job regardless of the format.

```
perl -pe 's/(p\.[A-Z][a-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[A-Z][a-z]{1,}.*?)p\.[A-Z][a-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[A-Z][a-z]{1,}/\1/' file
```

`perl -pe 's/<regex>/<substitution>/' file` will replace all occurrences of `<regex>` with `<substitution>`.

So to break the regex down:

`(p\.[A-Z][a-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[A-Z][a-z]{1,}.*?)` capture your pattern and anything after until it reaches the next condition. The `?` after the `*` is to make it non greedy, since you want it to stop the second time it the pattern matches. If you don't put the `?` and you have a third match, or more matches after, then it would remove the last match it found, since `*` would capture everything it can.

`p\.[A-Z][a-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[A-Z][a-z]{1,}` The second time we use your pattern. This time we don't capture it (no `()`), since we want to discard it anyways.

Anything following this pattern won't be matched and so it won't be affected. We then substitute `\1`, which is the first captured group, for the matched section, therefore "forgetting" the second match.

**Why perl over grep**

Grep is designed around search, so it will be easy to find patterns, but not so easy to format the output.